# CXF Client Changes request when deployed in Weblogic 12c

Tags: cxf, weblogic12c

I have a problem when I deploy a CXF client in weblogic 12c.

If I run the client with jetty I have no problem, this is the request:

```
<soap:Body>
  <ns2:getSegmento xmlns:ns2="http://api.service.web.dummy.com/" xmlns:ns3="http://model.api.dummy.com">
     <descripcionSegmento>EXTG</descripcionSegmento>
  </ns2:getSegmento>
```

But the same client in weblogic generates this request:

```
<env:Body>
  <getSegmento xmlns="http://api.service.web.dummy.com/" xmlns:ns3="http://model.api.dummy.com" xmlns:ns2="http://api.service.web.dummy.com/">
     <descripcionSegmento>EXTG</descripcionSegmento>
  </getSegmento>
```

I notice that the namespace is missing in weblogic, maybe something about dependencies?

Dependencies:

```
org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws:3.1.9
org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-http:3.1.9
org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-databinding-aegis:3.1.9
org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-corba:3.1.9
org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-jms:3.1.9
org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-security:3.1.9
```

Weblogic configuration:

```
<prefer-application-packages>
        <package-name>antlr.*</package-name>
        <package-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.*</package-name>
        <package-name>javax.wsdl.*</package-name>
        <package-name>org.antlr.*</package-name>
        <package-name>org.aopalliance.*</package-name>
        <package-name>org.apache.*</package-name>
        <package-name>org.apache.xerces.*</package-name>
        <package-name>org.aspectj.*</package-name>
        <package-name>org.hibernate.*</package-name>
        <package-name>org.mozilla.*</package-name>
        <package-name>org.slf4j.*</package-name>
        <package-name>org.springframework.*</package-name>
    </prefer-application-packages>
```

I have this error in the Service with the weblogic request:

```
Root cause of ServletException.
javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element (uri:"http://api.service.web.dummy.com/", local:"descripcionSegmento"). Expected elements are <{}descripcionSegmento>
```

Please provide any ideas/help, would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly this issue, I tried below which did not help:

1. Changed *wls:prefer-web-inf-classes* to true/false in *weblogic.xml* and/or *weblogic-application.xml*
2. Added dependencies in *wls:prefer-application-packages* of *weblogic-application.xml*
3. changed cxf version to latest

I ended up writing interceptor to replace the entire "*getSegmento*" element under body, like below:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.soap.SOAPBody;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage;

import org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapMessage;
import org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.saaj.SAAJOutInterceptor;
import org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault;
import org.apache.cxf.message.Message;
import org.apache.cxf.phase.AbstractPhaseInterceptor;
import org.apache.cxf.phase.Phase;
import org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptor;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;


public class MyRequestInterceptor extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor<SoapMessage> {

private List<PhaseInterceptor<? extends Message>> extras = new ArrayList<PhaseInterceptor<? extends Message>>(1);
public MyRequestInterceptor() {
super(Phase.USER_PROTOCOL);
extras.add(new SAAJOutInterceptor());
}
public Collection<PhaseInterceptor<? extends Message>> getAdditionalInterceptors() {
return extras;
}
public void handleMessage(SoapMessage message) throws Fault {
SOAPMessage msg = message.getContent(SOAPMessage.class);
try {
SOAPBody e = msg.getSOAPBody();
Element actionElement = msg.getSOAPPart().createElementNS("http://api.service.web.dummy.com/", 
        "ns2:getSegmento");
actionElement.appendChild(e.getFirstChild().getFirstChild());
e.replaceChild(actionElement, e.getFirstChild());
} catch (Exception e) {
throw new Fault(e);
}
}
}
```

And added this interceptor during client creation:

```
    JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factory = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
    factory.setServiceClass(serviceInterfaceClass);
    factory.setAddress(endpoint);
    MyRequestInterceptor interceptr = new MyRequestInterceptor();
    factory.getOutInterceptors().add(interceptr);
```

Comment: hope this helps!

Comment: For the next questions on this topic, could you elabore how you declare  prefer-application-packages because cxf documentation refer to

<prefer-application-packages>
        <package-name>javax.jws.*</package-name>
  </prefer-application-packages>

Answer (score 0):

if the application is an enterprise application (ear), then add the following tag in **weblogic-application.xml** 
`<prefer-application-packages> 
   <package-name>org.apache.cxf.*</package-name> 
</prefer-application-packages>`
If the application is web-application(war) then add the above lines in **weblogic.xml**
The prefer-application-packages element specifies a list of packages for classes that must always be loaded from the application.
please refer https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e21049/weblogic_xml.htm#WBAPP663

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in weblogic 12.2.1.4 v. cxf caused by the addition of the default ns in the parent element, which can be solved by excluding the jaxb/xml bind dependencies:-

```
<properties>
    <cxf.version>3.5.7</cxf.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
                <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```